# Converting 1 record with a start and end date into multiple records for each day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to know an efficient way of taking event records with a start date and end date and basically replicating that record for each day between the start and end date

So a record with a Start Date as 2014-01-01 and End Date as 2014-01-03 would become 3 records, one for each day

I have a date table if that helps.  I'm using SQL Server 2012

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already have date table, You can JOIN your table with date table to get all dates to have same record as your start and end date

```
 SELECT A.data,
    DT.startDate,
    DT.endDate
 FROM
 DateTable DT
 JOIN A
 ON A.StartDate >= DT.startDate
 And A.EndDate <= DT.endDate
```

Comment: you are awesome.. just what i needed.. and i modified and customized.. and it worked perfectly in an MS Access Query.

Answer (score 3):

use this query

```
declare @startDate datetime = getdate()
declare @endDate datetime = dateadd(day,10,getdate())


;with days as 
(
    select
        @startDate as StartDate,
        @endDate as EndDate,
        @startDate as CurrentDate,
        0 as i
    union all
    select 
        d.StartDate,
        d.EndDate,
        dateadd(day,d.i + 1,@startDate) as CurrentDate,
        d.i + 1 as i
    from days d
    where dateadd(day,d.i + 1,@startDate) < d.EndDate
)
select
*
from days d
```

Comment: This is just generation of dates, OP already has date table, need to expand his current tar data to all those dates

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @dt1 Datetime='2014-01-01'
DECLARE @dt2 Datetime='2014-01-03'
;WITH ctedaterange
     AS (SELECT [Dates]=@dt1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT [dates] + 1
         FROM   ctedaterange
         WHERE  [dates] + 1<= @dt2)
SELECT [dates]
FROM   ctedaterange
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COl1,COL2, split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') data 
FROM   (SELECT COl1,COL2, Cast ('<M>' 
                     + Replace(LEFT(Replicate(NAME+',', datediff(dd,startdate,endate),    Len(Replicate(NAME+',', datediff(dd,startdate,endate)))-1), ',''</M><M>') 
                 + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data 
    FROM   tablename) AS A 
   CROSS apply data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Query

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2014-01-01',
        @EndDate   DATE = '2014-01-03';

SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
      DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.number) - 1, @StartDate) AS Date_Range
FROM master..spt_values a
                   CROSS APPLY master..spt_values b;
```

### Result

```
Date_Range
2014-01-01
2014-01-02
2014-01-03
```